# SourceTree cannot resolve conflcts

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I right clicked on a file with conflicts and right clicked a file with conflicts in SourceTree 2.0.5.2. I selected "Resolve Conflicts > Launch External Merge Tool" but then nothing happened.

So I tried restarting SourceTree but now the option is grayed out.

I tried changing the merge tool to P4Merge, but the option is still grayed out.

How do I fix this so I can use the merge tool to resolve this conflict using SourceTree?

I'm running this under Mac OS 10.11.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a diff tool on your own, and then SourceTree will pick it up from the PATH. I use DiffMerge. Download it from [here](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/downloads.php), install it . You can also install it using [brew](http://brew.sh/) e.g

```
brew cask install diffmerge
```

The restart SourceTree, head to Preferences -> Diff -> and set DiffMerge to the sections Visual Diff Tool.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the cask. Installed it. Previously using P4Merge. However, I can't use either tool even with the preferences set, which is the problem I am having. I right click on the file with the conflict and there is no enabled option to resolve the conflict via *any* method. The "Resolve Conflict" menu has been totally greyed out since I clicked "Launch External Merge Tool" earlier.

Comment: Can you startup diffmerge from the command line? Open Terminal -> type  diffmerge .Does it start?

Comment: It starts from the commandline, but only after this error: https://gist.github.com/eComEvo/6ce7f792187fd16d3979